# Resizing the player window

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, avplayer

I have a UIview into which i am embedding a AVPlayer. Now when I play it, It somehow doesn't seem to cover the whole UIview. Below is the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var introVideo: UIView!

var player: AVPlayer!

func playIntro() {

    if let moviePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "intro", ofType: "mp4") {
        let movieURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: moviePath)
        player = AVPlayer(url: movieURL)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
        playerLayer.player = player
        playerLayer.frame = introVideo.bounds
        playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
        introVideo.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                               object: player.currentItem)        }
}
```

It appears like this :

[image]

how do I fix this

Comment: Try using `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill` instead of `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect`

Comment: Tried that. No luck

Comment: It makes sense to leave a reason for downvote, otherwise its a stupid move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I was calling this function in `viewDidLoad()`, But It was updating the view somehow on each load. So, for this reason the bounds should be updated in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    playIntro()
}
```